# What does -1 in the solution of this code mean? Why is xor with -1 equivalent to a bitwise invert / not?

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, riscv, twos-complement, ones-complement

Provide a minimal set of RISC-V instructions that may be used to implement the following pseudoinstruction:

```
not x5, x6   // bit-wise invert
```

solution:

```
xori x5, x6, -1
```

Comment: The value `-1` has all bits set in its binary representation - does that help?

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: The `xori` above does an xor of the value in `x6` and the value `111....111b` - that is, all bits in `x6` are flipped and the result assigned to `x5`.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Almost all computers these days (including all RISC-V variants) represent signed number in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  What this means is that negative numbers will be represented by bit patterns with their upper bit(s) set, and larger (closer to 0) negative numbers will be represented by bit patterns with a larger numeric value.  In particular, -1 will be the "largest" possible bit pattern (for any particular size), with all bits set to 1.

In RSIC-V, the 'immediate' instructions (those with the `i` suffix such as `xori` here) represent their immediate operand as a 12-bit signed two's complement number.  This will then be sign-extended to the size of the instruction (have the upper-most bit replicated) to be used as the operand to the ALU.

Comment: The OP's question did not mention negation or signed numbers, just bitwise inversion: notting/complement.

Comment: @ErikEidt: He's asking what -1 (which is a signed number) means in this context.